# RGBD camera noise model

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I saw there are many sensor models and plugins in order to simulate an RGB camera (either Asus, Kinect, etc). However, I do not see any way to include noise in both RGB and Depth, neither in Gazebo nor in the available plugins. I tried the  tag in the sensor but it seems to have no effect.

Is there any gazebo_ros plugin (or Gazebo plugin) somewhere to simulate the RGB camera more accurately?

Thank you!

For completeness, I include the part of the sensor of my model:

```
    <sensor type="depth" name="rgbd_camera">
        <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
                <width>640</width>
                <height>480</height>
                <format>R8G8B8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
                <near>0.05</near>
                <far>30</far>
            </clip>
            <noise>   <!-- This does apparently nothing neither RGB nor depth-->
                <type>gaussian</type>
                <mean>0.0</mean>
                <stddev>5.0</stddev>
            </noise>
        </camera>
        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <plugin name="multirotor_rgbd_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
            <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
            <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
            <pointCloudTopicName>depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
            <depthImageTopicName>depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
            <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
            <pointCloudCutoff>0.4</pointCloudCutoff>
            <pointCloudCutoffMax>5.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
            <frameName>rgbd_camera_link</frameName>
            <cameraName>rgbd_camera</cameraName>
            <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9946/rgbd-camera-noise-model/) by [Javi V](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1327/javi-v/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 57 on 2015-10-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdfjkl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2608/asdfjkl/) on 2016-05-26**:
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You will need to implement your own plugin to add depth noise.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AravindaDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2991/aravindadp/) on 2017-01-26**:
Hi @nkoenig

Is it the recommended way to achieve this? I think someone can simply add noise to camera sensor using noise model.

http://bit.ly/2j886ck

But this feature is aparently not available in DepthCamera sensor.

http://bit.ly/2k4DKH7

Any specific reasons to omit that or can we expect this feature in a future release?

Note: This requirement is also reported in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2125/depth-sensor-noise-model

**Comment by [RedJohn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4933/redjohn/) on 2018-06-01**:
Hi, did you manage to add noise to the depth point cloud? If so, did you write your own plugin or did you find another (easier) way? I'm stuck at the same problem.